# merge that works at word granularity instead of line

Tags: text-processing, software-rec, diff, patch

The old `diff`, `patch`, and `merge` programs, and their modern descendents in the form of version control systems work great for managing source code that can be edited concurrently by multiple people.

They are, however, strictly line oriented, and thus tend to fall down flat on text that is more free form.  In my particular case, I'm working with `latex` files edited by multiple people, and text is constantly reflowed -- adding or subtracting a word to a paragraph alters the line boundaries for the rest of the paragraph.  There are `diff` tools that highlight changes within a line (many modern GUI ones), or even handle reflowed text (`wdiff`, `git diff --word-diff`).  However, I've found nothing that handles three-way-merges or patching.

Does anyone know of a good tool that will do this automatically?  (Yes, I could chop the text up so as to put each word (and run of white space) onto a separate line.  Something like the format for `git diff --word-diff=porcelain` might   not be a bad choice.  But making this reversible and robust to an automated merge (including merge conflict markers) is not quite trivial).

Bonus points for a `git` merge driver.

Comment: possible cross-site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587626/git-merging-within-a-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wiggle (git://neil.brown.name/wiggle) can do this, and has a Debian package

Comment: I had looked at this one before, but I couldn't actually get it to work.  When I tried to do a three-way merge between ancestor:"a\nb c d\ne\n", branch1:"a\nb g c d\ne\n", and branch2:"a\nb c h d\ne\n", it spits out one of branch1 or branch2, claiming that a change had already been applied.   It turns out that the documentation is misleading ("if three files are listed, they are taken to contain the given text and the two other texts, in order", and that the ancestor needs to be the middle of the three arguments.  `wiggle --merge --help` clears this up.